# Polymer route observer - multiple instances causing logic issue

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Using Polymer 1.*

I have element `foo-bar` that has two instances.

```
<foo>
  <apple-pie>
    <foo-bar></foo-bar>
  </apple-pie>
</foo>

<bar>
  <cherry-pie>
    <foo-bar></foo-bar>
  </cherry-pie>
</bar>
```

element foo-bar has a observer for route changes:

```
  <app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>

   observers: ['_routeChanged(route.path)'],

    _routeChanged: function(newValue) {
      if (this.route.path.indexOf('main') > 0 &&
        this.firstLoadComplete &&
        this.oldRoutePath !== this.route.path) {
        this.cancel();
      }
      this.oldRoutePath = this.route.path;
    },
```

The issue I am having is `_routeChanged` fires twice for each instance per a single route change. This means `this.cancel()` fires twice....one for each element which is a issue for me.

When route changes, how can I make `this.cancel` only fire for the element that actually active?

Answer (score 0):

> When route changes, how can I make this.cancel only fire for the
>   element that actually active?

How exactly are you checking what element is in fact "active"?

You can have the host element control boolean flags to specify which is active, or bind it two-way to the parent element and have the logic there to say if it's active or not:

```
<foo active={{fooActive}}>
  <apple-pie>
    <foo-bar active={{fooActive}}></foo-bar>
  </apple-pie>
</foo>

<bar active={{barActive}}>
  <cherry-pie>
    <foo-bar active={{barActive}}></foo-bar>
  </cherry-pie>
</bar>
```

Then, add it to the foo-bar element:

```
  <app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>

   observers: ['_routeChanged(route.path)'],

    _routeChanged: function(newValue) {
      if (this.route.path.indexOf('main') > 0 &&
        this.firstLoadComplete &&
        this.oldRoutePath !== this.route.path &&
        this.active) {
        this.cancel();
      }
      this.oldRoutePath = this.route.path;
    },
```